# Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate the following strings:

```
org/com[2]/net[4]/uk@name  
org/com[2]/net[4]
```

Why doesn't the following regular expression work:

```
(((.*(\[.*?\])((\/)?)))|(\@(.*)))
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***Why doesn't the following regular expression work:***

Your expression can be broken down to

- `(.*(\[.*?\])((\/)?))`, or
- `(\@(.*))`

The former part can be broken down into

- `.*`, followed by
- `\[.*?\]` (which is not the same as `(\[.*\])?`) , possibly followed by
- `/`

---

Here's another suggestion:

```
String part = "[^/\\[\\]]+(\\[\\d*\\])?";
String pattern = String.format("%s(/%<s)*(@.*)?", part);
```

Test cases:

```
String[] tests = {
        "org/com[2]/net[4]/uk@name",
        "org/com[2]/net[4]",
        "org/com[2/net",
        "org/com2]/net",
        "org/com[2]/net",
        "org/com[2]/net/",
        "org/com[2]/net@blah",
};

for (String test : tests)
    System.out.println(test + ": " + test.matches(pattern));
```

**Output:**

```
org/com[2]/net[4]/uk@name: true
org/com[2]/net[4]: true
org/com[2/net: false
org/com2]/net: false
org/com[2]/net: true
org/com[2]/net/: false
org/com[2]/net@blah: true
```

Comment: Hi aioobe, thaks for a great solution, but how do I validate org/com[2]/net[4]/uk@name/test, which should provide me false. As there can be only one '@' and after some text( without  /,[,]) there should be noting else.

Comment: By validate I assume you mean "figure out if it follows the pattern or not". To validate string `str` you do `str.matches(pattern)` where `pattern` is the string from my answer.

Comment: If `@` is a forbidden character in the "parts" you change `[^/\\[\\]]` to `[^/\\[\\]@]` in the answer above. (Between `[^`...`]` you list all "forbidden" characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    String s = "org/com[2]/net[4]/uk@name";
    System.out.println(s.matches("^\\w+/\\w+\\[\\d\\]/\\w+\\[\\d\\](/\\w+@\\w+)?$"));
    s = "org/com[2]/net[4]";
    System.out.println(s.matches("^\\w+/\\w+\\[\\d\\]/\\w+\\[\\d\\](/\\w+@\\w+)?$"));
```